# Firebase - How can I filter similarly to equalTo() but instead check if it contains the value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have this database:

```
J-DSKFJASKDFJASKDJ:{
   username: "Burned"
},
J-KASDJFAKSDJFKDSJ:{
   username: "BurnedFirebase"
},
J-DFJKADSJFAKSDJFK:{
   username: "FirbaseFilteringIsVeryLackingThereforItSucks"
}
```

If I use this:

```
Query q = database.orderByChild("username").equalTo("Burned");
```

It will actually return only "`Burned`", although there is a `BurnedFirebase` in the database. That's because `equalTo()` doesn't work as a method such as `contains()`.

Is there a method similar to `contains()`? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: you can combine the startAt() and endAt() methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.

Comment: @UmarAta thanks for that link. But Frank doesn't provide an example and  I didn't understand how I could do that. I think to help future visitors, you should post an example before we close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @UmarAta do I just use `startAt("myQueryText").endAt("myQueryText")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your search is always at the beginning of the word (you're not searching for ned and expecting Burned to come up), you can use a high unicode character:

```
query.startAt("Burned").endAt("Burned\uf8ff")
```

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries

```
...dinosaursRef.orderByKey().startAt("b").endAt("b\uf8ff")...
```

> The \uf8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point
>   in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in
>   Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b.