# Do local writes to Firebase RTDB or Firestore with attached listeners cost a Read Op?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In this firestore official [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#events-local-changes) , it says that

> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners
>   immediately. This is because of an important feature called "latency
>   compensation." When you perform a write, your listeners will be
>   notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend

1. So Firestore client (that posted this data) will not fetch this data  via listeners from server ?
2. Will this still be charged as a Read Op (in case data is not fetched from server) ?
3. Is this concept true for Realtime Database as well ?

I tested it with a client writing new object to `/chats/chatRoomId/` and same client having listeners for `child_added` on `/chats/chatRoomId/`. I turned off the internet, still the pushing new data was reported OK (due to offline ability i guess), and listeners also reported receiving new data (even without server access)

I want to structure my chat app's DB, such that i can cut cost on unnecessary reads (if there are any) in chat DB structure given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879031/firebase-database-structure-for-chat-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase) **recommended by @FrankVanPuffelen** from Firebase.

> ```
> chats: {
>   $roomId: {
>     $messageId: {
>       senderId: "..."
>       message: "..."
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

**Example** :

Consider a 1:1 chat, where userA and userB (on different clients) are in a chat room, and both have added a listener to `/chats/chatRoomId/`. Now if userA pushes a new message in `chatRoomId`, both users A&B will receive this new message through their listeners. Isn't this a waste of Bandwidth and/or a Read Op cost for userA, since he himself pushed it, and probably wont require fetching it from server.

If the local writes will NOT COST me a server read for attached listener, i will store messages from userA and userB in same path `/chats/chatRoomId/` as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879031/firebase-database-structure-for-chat-application)

Otherwise, i want to have a DB structure so that userA will only listen to messages from userB. e.g. 
userA will push new msg for userB to `/chats/uid_A/uid_B/` and userA will listen on `/chats/uid_B/uid_A/` where userB is pushing new msgs for userA. And client will locally merge the two paths sorted by time, to get one chat stream.

It will potentially save me 50% of reads, and Huge savings on firebase bill.

**EDIT on 03/05/2019 :**

Adding a picture for clarity of question :
[image: Pay for an unnecessary Read]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. So Firestore client (that posted this data) will not fetch this data via listeners from server?

When you write some data locally a snapshot listener will be invoked immediately. This means that your listeners will be notified right away because you have added some new data. But remember, this operation is happening before the data is sent to the Firebase servers.

> 2. Will this still be charged as a Read Op (in case data is not fetched from the server)?

No. As long as you have cached data and you didn't sync the data with Firebase servers, you won't be charged with any "Read Op" in Firestore.

> 3. Is this concept true for the Realtime Database as well?

No, it's not. Firebase Realtime Database has a different concept for [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

> I want to structure my chat app's DB, such that I can cut cost on unnecessary reads (if there are any) in the chat DB structure given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919435/do-local-writes-to-firebase-rtdb-or-firestore-with-attached-listeners-cost-a-rea) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase) recommended by @FrankVanPuffelen from Firebase.

Both examples are for Firebase Realtime Database, and both explain a very good way for creating a chat app. If you consider at some point to try using Cloud Firestore for a chat app, here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

I also think that you might be interested in the following article:

- https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Alex, however, i still did not get the answer for realtime DB. I understand that it has different pricing policy, but i want to know (1) if write (a new child) to Realtime DB at `chats/chatroomId`, triggering the local listener at same path, will cost me Bandwidth (in Realtime DB terms). PS: My chat app is already working with Realtime DB, i just want to cut the cost, if possible. (2) Do you recommend Firestore over Realtime DB, as a cost effective solution ?

Comment: 1. The listeners will work in the same way. There is no cost when writing data to cache. Only when you synchronize data to the cloud. 2. I recommend using both.

Comment: I am sorry i am a little dumb in understanding things, unless it is explicitly said.  "Synchronize data to cloud incurs cost" -> Does this synchronisation includes reading data from server (via listener) once data is written to cloud ? I am talking about the first read that was initially read via cache (not the subsequent reads that will of course cost bandwidth)

Comment: The answer is yes. The things stay like so. Once you write data, you first write data it is written on user's device. If you are online, the data is written on the server. All the reads will be from cache ad looking as that don't remains unchanged. Ok?

Comment: I am again very sorry @Alex, your replies are a bit confusing. In the "answer" in point 2 you replied that read will NOT be charged. But in your 2nd comment, you answered "Yes" (synchronization incures COST, which includes reading via listener)

Comment: May be my question was not clear enough, so i try again => In realtime database, in a 1:1 chat case, where userA and userB (on different clients) are in a chat room, and both have added a listener to `/chats/chatRoom1/`. Now if userA pushes a new message "Hello" in `chatRoom1`, both users A&B will receive this new message "Hello" through their listeners (A will receive it via local cache). For this particular message, RTDB will charge (1) Data Write BW [OK], (2) Data Read Bandwidth for UserB [OK]. (3) Will data read bandwidth be charged for UserA as well ? (Before or After synchronisation)

Comment: In case the data does not come from the server (is coming from the cache), there is no cost. Synchronization with the server incures costs. Regarding your example, "both users A&B will receive this new message" - correct. "A will receive it via local cache" - if both are online, both will receive the message. A will send the message to the server and second will get the message from the server. 1. Correct 2. Correct. 3. Yes, if he is online. If he is offline there is no cost until he is going online. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes. This reply is perfect  :-)  I understood, Thank you. I will try switching to the DB structure I mentioned at the end of my question, it would save me one Read cost per message Write (compared to the Frank's recommended DB structure for chat )

Comment: Just this final confirmation. Since they say that "a pic is worth thousand comments", can you please check this pic ( https://imgur.com/hbZfBdx ) and confirm that i have to pay for that extra read ?